# Redirect all subdomains that are not on a list and non-SSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My website is setup so it accepts wildcard subdomains.

I want to ONLY allow a few subdomains that are in a list like:

```
help.example.com
blog.example.com
```

If a request comes in for say:

```
   asdf.example.com
```

I want to redirect the requests to:

```
   www.example.com
```

Also, if a request comes in like:

```
example.com
```

I want to redirect to:

www.example.com

How can I do this?

I will then also want to redirect any non-ssl to SSL domains.

Comment: Which webserver you are using?

Comment: @dthal I have to do this at the application layer, I dont' control the web server.